# get selected "value" of declared text-field / BootstrapVue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, emit

I have a `b-form-select` field and `emit` my `value-field` to my parent, but I need the selected `text-field` too..

Here is the needed code to show what I mean:

In my template:

`<b-form-select v-model="selected" :options="getOptions" text-field="Name" value-field="Rank"></b-form-select>`

but if I `console.log(this.selected)`, I get of course the value `Rank` which I have selected. But is it also possible to get the `text-field` ?

Here is my script to show how my selected works:

```
computed: {
 getOptions() {
    const array = [];
    const person = this.data.find((i) => i.name === this.name);
    for (let key in person.persons) {
      array.push(person.persons[key]);
    }
    return array;
  },
}
```

my json data:

```
[
    {
        "name": "XXX",
        "persons": {
            "1": {
                "Name": "Max",
                "Rank": "1"
                },
            "2": {
                "Name": "Peter",
                "Rank": "2"
            },
            "3": {
                "Name": "Harry",
                "Rank": "1"
            },
            "4": {
                "Name": "Jake",
                "Rank": "0"
            }

        }
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have the value available, as well as the list of options you can simply add a new computed field to get the selected values `text-field`

```
computed: {
 getOptions() {
    const array = [];
    const person = this.data.find((i) => i.name === this.name);
    for (let key in person.persons) {
      array.push(person.persons[key]);
    }
    return array;
  },
  selectedOption() {
    if (!this.selected) {
      return null;
    }

    return Object.values(this.getOptions).find((option) => {
      return option.Rank === this.selected;
    });
  }
}
```

Then access `selectedOption.Name` or `selectedOption.Rank`. If you put the `Name` and `Rank` into variables / data attributes as well you can also make it more generic.

Update:

Changed to Object.values

Comment: just to make clear.. i think you understood my question wrong. I've updated it with my json data - my text field and value field are in the same nested json. Does your code work in case of this too?

Comment: I actually still think I got it right - I just updated my answer to actually work with your json due to the object structure where i thought that it's an array.